# How to have a row of columns and text fitting within them properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:
This is my test page:

```html
<TITLE>Auto trader</title>
<style>
div.at11 {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 14px;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 123px;
height: 119px;
border: 2px solid;
padding: 3px;
align-items: center;
margin: 10px;
white-space: pre-line;
}
div.at11 img {
height: 10mm;
}
div.at12 {
font-size: 12px;
border: 2px solid;
width: 236px;
height: 123px;
padding: 3px;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
margin:10px;
float: left;
white-space: pre-line;
}
div.at12 body {
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-bottom: 4mm;
}
div.at12 img {
filter: sepia(100%);
height: 14.5mm;
margin-left: 3px;
float: left;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
div.article {
display: inline;
columns: 5;
border-left: 1px;
border-right: 1px;
}
</style>
<div class="article">
<div class="at11">HONDA CIVIC
<p>1993, 1.5 gl</p>
<b>£1,000 
Tel: Blackpool 01253 790400</b></div>
<div class="at12"><b>HONDA ACCORD 2.0i SR</b>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/93SE_4-dr_3-qtr_Ft_01.jpg/280px-93SE_4-dr_3-qtr_Ft_01.jpg">
1995, good condition for year, 100,000 miles, flame red
<b>£1,000</b>
Tel: Nottingham 0115 496 0000</div>
</div>
<div class="at11"><img src="111.jpg">
HONDA CIVIC
<p>1993, 1.5 gl</p>
<h3>£1,000</h3></div>
<div class="at12"><b>HONDA ACCORD 2.0i SR</b>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/93SE_4-dr_3-qtr_Ft_01.jpg/280px-93SE_4-dr_3-qtr_Ft_01.jpg">
1995, good condition for year, 100,000 miles, flame red
<b>£1,000</b>
Tel: Nottingham 0115 496 0000</div>
</div>
<div class="at11"><div><img src="3.jpg"></div>
HONDA CIVIC
1992, black £1,000 Tel: 01362 963000 Norwich</div>
<div class="at12"><b>HONDA ACCORD 2.0i SR</b>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/93SE_4-dr_3-qtr_Ft_01.jpg/280px-93SE_4-dr_3-qtr_Ft_01.jpg">
1995, good condition for year, 100,000 miles, flame red
<b>£1,000</b>
Tel: Nottingham 0115 496 0000</div>
</div><div class="at12"><b>HONDA ACCORD 2.0i SR</b>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/93SE_4-dr_3-qtr_Ft_01.jpg/280px-93SE_4-dr_3-qtr_Ft_01.jpg">
1995, good condition for year, 100,000 miles, flame red
<b>£1,000</b>
Tel: Nottingham 0115 496 0000</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I want to try and do is make my print version look like this when a PDF version:
[image: Magazine stock photo with images / design to emulate]

; the adverts being 31.5mm width x 31.5mm height for one div, 32.5mm x 62.5mm for the other and the print version looking roughly magazine-like.

I can do the image as filter:sepia in CSS but am not really sure how to with CSS apart from @media print in CSS.

This is an inline stylesheet as it's a test page but will be a .css file in the proper thing.

If you could help, I'd much appreciate it.